# Find an item from a list based on an ID

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this class

```
public class item
{
        public int itemID { get; set; }
        public int itemValue { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a variable

```
public List<item> itemList;
```

I am trying to search and find an item in itemList that has itemID=i using lambda.
Normally, the function without lamda is as follow:

```
public item FindItem(int i)
{
foreach (var t in itemList)
{
  if (t.itemID==i)
    return t;
}
return null;
}
```

and I tried to replace it with this lambda

```
item Item = itemList.Where(x=>x.itemID==i).Select(x=>x);
```

I got an error saying:

```
Error   1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<item>' to 'item'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

How should I correct this? I am still learning lambda, Linq

Comment: Use `First`, `Single`, `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` .. depending on what should happen. The problem is `Where` and `Select` return an `IEnumerable<?>` which is not an `item`.

Comment: @user2864740 considering his code, only `FirstOrDefault` will fit. `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception if there would be many items, but his code won't. `Single` with throw an exception if no items would match. `First` would do the same.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov That's fine. The poster can STFM :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are returning `null` if no item is found, use next code as equivalent:

```
public item FindItem(int i)
{
    return itemList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.itemId == i);
}
```

`FirstOrDefault` is described as `Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

`item` type is a class, thus default value is `null`.

You are using `Select` after `Where` clause, which is basically a projection after filtering. It takes a sequence of type `A` and returns a sequence of type `B`. You need to fold a sequence, in other words to find one item, that match some criteria. There are quite a few of folding queries in LINQ (`First`, `Single`, `Max`, `Last`, `Aggregate`, etc), they all return one item of type `A` from a sequence of type `A`. `FirstOrDefault` seems to fit well to your current C# implementation.

Comment: Thank you llya. Would return itemList.FirstOrDefault(item=>itemID==i) identical to return itemList.Where(item=>itemID==i).FirstOrDefault() ?

Comment: @user1205746 yes, they are identical.